# Clarifications on limits notes

Tags: real-analysis, limits

[image]

Would someone be so kind as to explain to me the reasoning behind the part highlighted in blue?
Especially, why is there a need to make explicit
$$x^4>c \left(2 x^3+1\right)?$$
Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

The first line in blue is true but (from my point of view) adds nothing to the argument. Concentrate on the second line.

If $x>1$ then also $1<x^3$ and $2\,x^3+1<2\,x^3+x^3=3\,x^3$.

Comment: A typo. It should be $3x^3$, **not** $32x^3$.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Thanks, corrected.

Comment: Going back to the notes,
If instead of $$3 x^3$$, we have $$3x^4$$, would it work equally well?

Comment: @guest, $\forall x\gt 1$, we have $x^4\gt x^3$. So, it works.

Comment: Could I ask why for all x>1 in this case?

Comment: You need it for $x$ large. $x>1$ turns out to be convinient as a first step. Finally you get $x>\max(1,3\,c)$.